# header not setting Content-type as expected

Tags: php, json, http-headers

I have a joomla php/script that returns json but as text/html because if I return it as application/json it downloads a file instead of interpretating it.

To do this I use:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8",true);

flush();

echo json_encode(($imgChanging>0)?$thmbName:0);
```

which works fine on 2 different servers (**php 5.3.3-7 + squeeze14** and **php 5.4.4-2**), but it doesn't work in another server with **php 5.3.14**, instead of returning text/html it returns application/json.  Everything else works fine, and I haven't found this bug for this php version. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure there are the same extensions enabled for php and same modules in http server ?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is very rarely a good way to describe the symptoms of your problem.

Comment: Sounds more like a hacky workaround than a real solid solution.

Comment: @Evert, I fixed it, it returns application/json instead of text/html as I set the header.